# Is there anyway to reset webclient?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, webclient

Im experiencing problem with webclient to parse some very sensitive webpage. Somehow, webclient failed to do some task, and i dont even know why, no exception, no error, just simple not working (this is not the problem from the site)

I run webclient in a loop, however, only the first request was success, all the next requests are failed. When i restart the application, the same result appear, the first request always succeed, while all other request are failed.

Im sure all webclient are disposed properly, but i don't know what is the problem, is webclient saving information even after dispose?

Please guide me how to clear everything, reset everything and start brand new webclient.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Count; i++)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0) (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
        byte[] arr = wc.DownloadData(url);

        if (arr.Length > 0)
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": SUCCESS");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ": FAILED");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebClient` will not share any information between instances.
You probably have a different problem.

For example, the site might ignore requests that happen too frequently.

You should run Fiddler and check exactly what is happening.

Also, try adding `Thread.Sleep(5000)` in the loop and see whether anything changes.  (In Fiddler)

Comment: yes, in my program, i tried both fiddler and thread.sleep(5000) and it don't help. the site, in my actual request by hand, i can request to it without any problem. also, why it's only the first request is posible? i tried to run first request, close, run again, and it work totally fine.

Comment: Run Fiddler and see what the server is responding.  (And whether there are any differences in the raw requests.  Also, try making two requests using Fiddler's request builder.

Comment: for the first answer, there's no different, but server respond Content-length 0. i tried to restart and run again, i can receive data, but all the next are content-length:0, if it's actually dispose everything, i suppose to loop successfully, right? but i need to restart the program and run again, very trouble. 2nd, request builder are not good for this case since i need to run a parse for some token before request the succeeding page...

Comment: Then you're probably getting the URL for the second page wrong.

Comment: it's the same, the loop parse on the same page. i did this before and it work without a clue (i dont even know why it work) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123096/c-webclient-problem-with-looping-download/2123215#2123215 | but since there are some change on the target website, i need to rewrite code, since i dont have a clue what i did last time, now, i need to understand just why this happen.. :( i been write, rewrite code since 5h ago. but no luck

Comment: @DucDigital: how did you resolve this? what was your conclusion on why this was happening? and what did you do for the workaround?

Comment: I tried to double parse, some how it work by simply duplicate the code. I haven't touch this problem since then.