# HtmlAgilityPack full page loading

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, url-parsing

So, I have code which downloads pictures from parsed links. Downloading/parsing works well, but I have a problem with loading full content of this page.

```
/*
 * https://shikimori.org/animes/38256-magia-record-mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica-gaiden-tv
 * For testing
 */

class Program
{
    static string root = @"C:\Shikimori\";
    static List<string> sources = new List<string>();

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter link: ");
        var link = Console.ReadLine(); // enter there link from above
        link += "/art";

        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        web.BrowserTimeout = TimeSpan.FromTicks(0);

        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        try
        {
            htmlDocument = web.LoadFromBrowser(link); //ones per, like, 30m loading almost all page with whole pictures
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("an error has occured.");
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        var name = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            .Equals("b-options-floated mobile-phone_portrait r-edit")).ToList();

        //var divlink = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
        //    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
        //    .Equals("container packery")).ToList();

        var alink = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
            .Equals("b-image")).ToList();

        foreach(var a in alink)
        {
            sources.Add(a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty));
        }

        var tmp = Regex.Replace(name[0].GetDirectInnerText(), "[^a-zA-Z0-9._]", string.Empty);

        root += (tmp+"\\");

        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sources.Count; i++)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var test = sources[i].Split(';').Last().Replace("url=", string.Empty);
                try
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(new Uri(test), root + test.Split('/').Last().Replace("&amp", string.Empty).Replace("?", string.Empty));
                    Console.WriteLine($"Image #{i + 1} download successfully!");
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Image #{i + 1} download unsuccessfully...");
                }
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

The issue is: Its working probably ones per 30 minutes, i guess? And working not that good, as I expected. Html Parser does not loading the content fully. If link has 100+ pictures, in good condition Im getting like from 5 to 15. If link (for example: https://shikimori.one/animes/1577-taiho-shichau-zo) has around 30 pictures, Its likely can parse it all. (other options not tested. Also tried to parse google pictures, Its loading like one page of the link tho, not reaching the button "More results")

I assume that the site is protected from bots, and therefore it does not always respond to requests from my program, or something like that. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140176/is-there-anyway-to-reset-webclient) as I understand has the same problem, but still no answer.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Thread.Sleep(3000) means the execution of this thread will be delayed for 3 seconds. (roughly speaking..) It is not 30 minutes. This source code first downloads the html content of the web page and then finds <a class="b-image" and then tries to download all the images.  Since the code does not report any of the exception details and just prints out "unsuccessful", we don't have the root cause of the mishap. change to `catch(Exception downloadError) { Console.WriteLine(downloadError); }` and let us know the full message

Comment: @oguz-ozgul, let me explain a little more. There is on issue with it for all time I compiling this code. But, as I said Its loading page ones per ~30m [fully](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mnMdCKSsgn4PGoyzQXUoJvQHafwxJup4), and after I run this again I have [not fully](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G6EyTApsDJKqzEgqxqows2LgulxCxiUv) loaded page. You can check yourself what htmlDocument contains. If I wait for ~30m Its again works as first run.  
Its always loading some html source code, but not always completely. (with ~30m delay between starting a program)

Comment: Then as you say, the web site has some kind of restriction on their end. The best suggestion I can make is to set a good user-agent string to your web client (like your user-agent string when requesting this site from Chrome browser) to pass any restrictions which checks for the validity of the user-agent header.

Comment: I am not very good at this. How can I set user-agent in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841540/setting-the-user-agent-header-for-a-webclient-request The answer here explains how. You can use something like this.            Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36

Comment: @oguz-ozgul, if it should looks like `web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G532F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.105 Mobile Safari/537.36"` Its doesnt work, all the same. Found this user-agent [here](https://olegon.ru/user_agents.txt).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Can you please catch exception and print out full details as I mentioned earlier

Comment: @oguz-ozgul, there is no any exeptions. Its just sometime loading fully, sometime not. You also can remove the try exeption blocks, nothing changes. Its just to be safe. Maybe I didnt get exactly what you want, (here)[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-VDdjX65FaIihwnjnfRZpZDy8gKC3Zz4] is solution of my program. If you can check it with yourself and help with my problem, I will be very grateful.

Comment: No promises, but I will try

Comment: @oguz-ozgul, Thanks! Let me know if something works out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I messed up the projects a bit. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aU_vKENszOVrtFe8MH3tJfGZQHNjajfe) is the last one.

Comment: I tried it, and downloaded https://shikimori.org/animes/38256-magia-record-mahou-shoujo-madoka-magica-gaiden-tv but it found no `<a>` there. Count = 0. Sorry.